# Einen über den Durst trinken

Tags: phrase

Der Ausdruck "**Einen über den Durst trinken**" bedeutet im Prinzip "sich betrinken" - so viel ist klar.

### Frage:

Aber soll damit wörtlich lediglich angedeutet werden, dass man Alkohol trinkt, um seinen Durst zu löschen, oder soll es bedeuten, dass man sogar "über den Durst" hinaus, bzw. "über das Durstlöschen hinaus" trinkt, obwohl der Durst längst gestillt ist?

### Weitere Gedanken:

- Mit "Durst" könnte einerseits das körperlich spürbare Verlangen
  gemeint sein, Flüssigkeit aufzunehmen, andererseits könnte es auch
  metaphorisch für "Lust" oder "Verlangen" (hier nach Alkohol) stehen.
  Zweiteres würde den Satz zu einer verharmlosenden Form von "Um meine
  Lust zu befriedigen / Über meine Lust hinaus habe ich einen
  getrunken." machen.
- Das Wort "über" könnte einerseits das Überschreiten einer Grenze -
  der Durstgrenze - suggerieren. Andererseits könnte das "über" auch
  eine ähnliche Funktion erfüllen wie zum Beispiel im Satz: "*Über* den
  ganzen Trubel habe ich vergessen, ihr zum Geburtstag zu gratulieren."
  Die Bedeutung wäre dann so etwas wie "weil" oder "wegen": "*Wegen*
  des Trubels habe ich...", bzw. "*Wegen* meines Durstes habe ich einen
  getrunken."

"Einen" bedeutet wahrscheinlich "einen Schnaps", "einen Humpen", "einen Schluck" oder ähnliches.

- Mit Schnaps löscht aber vermutlich niemand seinen körperlichen Durst, eher seinen metaphorischen.
- Einen Schluck über die Durstgrenze hinaus zu trinken, ergibt für mich nicht viel Sinn, wenn man aussagen will, dass man sich betrinkt. Da man zum Zeitpunkt des Erreichens der Durstgrenze wahrscheinlich längst betrunken ist, macht ein Schluck mehr auch keinen Unterschied. Eher könnte man damit ausdrücken, dass man bis zum körperlichen Unwohlsein getrunken hat. (Wasserbauch, Bauchschmerzen, volle Blase)
- Ein Humpen (etwa Bier) macht noch am meisten Sinn, wenn man sagen will, dass man über die Durstgrenze hinaus trinkt, aber auch die metaphorische Variante funktioniert.

Zusammenfassend finde ich, dass "einen" eher darauf hindeutet, dass ein metaphorischer Durst (eine Lust) befriedigt wird, da es dann mehr Möglichkeiten gibt, etwas Konkretes für die bewusste Lücke "einen", die zu schließen offenbar der Fantasie des Lesers/Zuhörers überlassen wird, einzusetzen. Da der Satz so zur humoristischen Verharmlosung wird, bzw. ein vorgespieltes körperliches Verlangen zur Rechtfertigung angeführt wird, deutet das nicht darauf hin, dass hier davon die Rede ist, generell seinem Durst mit alkoholischen Getränken beizukommen oder seine Lust nach eben solchen zu befriedigen, anstatt vom Erreichen der scheinbar offensichtlichen Durstgrenze, was doch eher eine "wissenschaftliche" Denkweise nahelegen würde, die nicht ganz zur Situation passt?

Das sind aber alles Spekulationen meinerseits und ich habe mich gefragt, ob es eine Antwort auf diese Frage jenseits der Spekulation gibt.

Comment: Und wieviele Fragen sind das jetzt?

Comment: Ich hätte bei dieser Phrase eher nach der Bedeutung von »einen« gefragt. Was »über den Durst« bedeutet ist relativ offensichtlich. Aber warum ausgerechnet »einen« (männlich, singular)? Warum nicht »etwas«?

Comment: @unknown: Eine. Danke für den Hinweis.

Comment: @Hubert: Stimmt, das ist auch bemerkenswert, aber eher etwas für eine neue Frage, die den Ausspruch "einen Trinken" thematisiert. Allerdings hat mich der Hinweis zu neuem Nachdenken angeregt. Die Frage ist nun erweitert und besser formatiert.

Comment: Früher war die Trinkwasserqualität oft nicht besonders gut. Damals wurde wesentlich mehr Bier getrunken, und sehr wohl auch zum Durst löschen, auch, da durch den Brauprozess deutlich weniger Krankheitserreger im bier waren als im Brunennwasser. Es wurde also reichlich bier (und auch Wein) gegen den Durst getrunken.

Comment: @Burki: Aha! Das klingt nach einer einleuchtenden Idee! Und es spricht sehr dafür, dass tatsächlich "über die Durstgrenze hinaus" gemeint ist, nicht wahr? Da jeder gegen den Durst Bier getrunken hat, war der Zustand, in den man dadurch geriet, quasi "normal". War jemand ganz besonders betrunken, musste er folglich mehr getrunken haben als nur um den Durst zu stillen. Danke für diesen Kommentar!

Comment: Ich habe [hier](http://www.kraemer-halunken.de/trinken.html) noch eine Beschreibung mittelalterlicher Trinkgewohnheiten gefunden, die sich mit anderen deckt, die cih früher gelesen habe.

Comment: @Burki: Nochmals vielen Dank für deine Mühe! Dieser Artikel ist sehr informativ und bekräftigt die These, dass "über den Durst hinaus" gemeint sein muss. Möchtest du eine eigene Antwort auf meine Frage basierend auf diesen geschichtlichen Gegebenheiten verfassen? Ich würde sie dann gern als am hilfreichsten akzeptieren.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Im Mittelalter war insbesondere in den Städten die Trinkwasserqualität nicht besonders gut.
Da es kein Verständnis für Hygiene und für die Übertragungswege von Krankheiten gab, kam es oft vor, dass Latrinen in unmittelbarer Nähe von Brunnen errichtet wurden.
Die Bevölkerung trank damals vor Allem Bier und Wein, je nach den Vermögensverhältnissen.
Hierbei ist anzumerken, dass der Alkoholgehalt von Bier und Wein damals meist geringer war als das heute der Fall ist.
Es ist also nicht unbedingt davon auszugehen, dass jeder jederzeit betrunken war.

Eine Ausführlichere Zusammenfassung von Ess- und Trinkgewohnheiten findet sich zum Beispiel [hier](http://www.kraemer-halunken.de/trinken.html).

Daher nehme ich an, dass

> Einen über den Durst trinken

Tatsächlich meint, dass der so bezeichnete das Bier oder den Wein nich nur zum Durstlöschen  getrunken hat, was der Normalfall wäre, sondern eben darüber hinaus.

Answer (score 4):

### Durst

Durst ist ein Existenzbedürfnis, und zwar jenes nach Wasser, das man trinken möchte. Wenn ein Existenzbedürfnis über längere Zeit nicht gestillt wird, droht der Tod.

Das Bedürfnis Flüssigkeiten zu trinken, die nicht so gut geeignet sind Durst zu stillen (Kaffee, Wein), kann streng genommen nicht als Durst bezeichnet werden, sondern stellt eher eine Form eines Appetits oder Gustos dar.

Getränke mit einem Alkohol-Anteil von mehr als ca. 5% eignen sich generell schlecht um Durst zu stillen. Sie führen eher zu den typischen Vergiftungssymptomen (bekannt als »Rausch«; Alkohol ist ein Rauschgift) als dass sie den Durst stillen. Aber auch wer regelmäßig seinen Durst mit Bier oder verdünntem Wein (Spritzer, Schorle) löscht (beides enthält rund 5 % Alkohol), wird schon nach wenigen Wochen abhängig (Alkohol ist auch ein Suchtgift). Also ist auch hier Vorsicht geboten.

### über den Durst

Wenn man keinen Durst hat, und trotzdem alkoholische Getränke trinkt, nimmt man also Flüssigkeit in einem Maß auf, das **über** das gesunde und normale Verlangen nach Wasser hinaus geht. Das ist gemeint, wenn man »*über den Durst*« trinkt.

Comment: Okay, tut mir Leid. Die Bedeutung von Durst ist mir schon klar. Ich dachte nur, dass es hilfreich sein könnte, die Bedeutung von "Durst" in der Phrase zu untersuchen, um die eigentliche Frage zu klären.
Bestehen keine Zweifel daran, dass tatsächlich vom Überschreiten der Durstgrenze die Rede ist? Betrunken ist man doch schon vorher? (Siehe meinen neu hinzugefügten Gedankengang.)

Comment: @S818: Es gibt hier ein paar Regeln. Eine Regel besagt vereinfacht: Stelle pro Frage nur eine Frage. Du hast aber zwei Fragen gestellt. Eine davon lautete wörtlich: »Ist mit "Durst" überhaupt das körperlich spürbare Verlangen gemeint?« Und jetzt regst du dich darüber auf, dass ich diese Frage beantwortet habe? - Eine andere, ebenfalls sehr wichtige Regel besagt: Wenn du deine Frage editierst, dann nur um Rechtschreib- und Grammatikfehler zu korrigieren, aber nicht um sie inhaltlich zu ändern. Genau das hast du aber in erheblichem Maße getan!

Comment: Die Regeln sind mir klar und ich halte sie auch nach bestem Gewissen ein. Zum Editieren steht in der Tour: "Use edits to fix mistakes, improve formatting, or **clarify the meaning of a post**." Die eigentliche Frage war immer die selbe. Das mit dem Durst gehörte zu meinen Überlegungen, was ich nun per Edit **clarified** habe, nachdem ich darauf hingewiesen wurde. Aufregen tust nur du dich, welchen Grund hätte ich dazu? Ich habe eine unbezahlte Antwort auf meine Frage von dir erhalten, die zum Ziel hatte, sie zu beantworten. Mehr als mich entschuldigen kann ich nicht.

Answer (score 3):

Ja, gemeint ist über den Durst hinaus, also mehr, als das bloße Löschen des Durstes erfordern würde.

Comment: In anderen Foren im Internet, wo nach der Bedeutung dieser Phrase diskutiert wird, gibt es teilweise auch Stimmen, die sagen, dass sie generell erstmal nichts mit dem Betrinken zu tun hat, sondern mit dem Trinken über die Durstgrenze hinaus (auch ohne Alkohol). Aber niemand kann das so recht begründen. Gibt es keine Kenntnis über den Ursprung dieses Ausspruchs? Ich konnte keinen finden bisher.